# Is there a way to substring or cut a part of value of a unix variable without using echo?

Tags: date, command

Is there a way to substring or cut a part of value of a unix variable without using echo?

For example i have a variable containing a date.

```
pDate=2020-06-22
```

I need to pass the year and month into separate variables.. i will use them in an if else statement that will determine the quarter of the year.

I don't use a script... I'm coding in Datastage and this is for the execute command stage. I used this command:

```
pDate=2020-06-22; pMonth= echo $pDate | cut -c6-7
```

so it's giving me the month "06" in the command output of the execute command stage of the DS sequence job.. I need the month only as variables and not to be output in the command output because the job is failing if it have multiple outputs.

Comment: What shell do you have access do? bash? /bin/sh?

Comment: We are using ksh.

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Comment: You need command substitution syntax to assign to the variable: `pMonth=$(echo "$pDate" | cut -d- -f2)`

Comment: Thank you glenn! Code is working now thanks to your help!!! 

Answer (score 4):

Portably, you can use shell parameter expansion:

```bsh
$ pDate=2020-06-22
$ year=${pDate%%-*}
$ yearmonth=${pDate%-*}
$ month=${yearmonth#*-}
$ echo $year
2020
$ echo $month
06
```

With ksh, you can read from a herestring:

```bsh
$ IFS="-" read year month day <<<"$pDate"
$ echo "$year .. $month .. $day"
2020 .. 06 .. 22
```

Comment: substring expansion also probably works in ksh: `ksh -c 'd=2020-06-22; echo ${d:0:4} .. ${d:5:2} .. ${d:8:2}'`